# Updating client's view based on actions of another client

Tags: java, html, spring, web

So i'm trying to develop a simple web-messenger on Spring and here's the problem that i cannot even find an approach to. When user A sends a message, his view is updated, showing new message (for now it's pretty simple logic: when the message is sent using POST request, it is saved to database, and then corresponding controller redirects user to GET controller, showing contents of the message table from the database. At this moment, database already contains new message). What i want to achieve is when user A sends his message, view of the user B on the other end needs to be updated as well, without refreshing the page in browser. Is there a way to do that in Spring?

Here's my Entity classes, controllers and simple html form, if needed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_chat")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Chat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AuthUser> users;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chat")
    @Nullable
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private boolean isPrivate;
    private LocalDateTime lastMessageDateTime;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_message")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    @Nullable
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> pictures;
    private LocalDateTime sendingTime;
    @ManyToOne
    private AuthUser sender;
    @ManyToOne
    private AuthUser receiver;
    boolean isForwarded;
    @ManyToOne
    private Chat chat;

}
```

```
 @GetMapping("/{chatId}")
    public String getChat(@PathVariable String chatId, Model model){
        Chat chat = chatService.findChatById(Long.parseLong(chatId));
        model.addAttribute("chat", chat);
        return "chat";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{chatId}/send")
    public String sendMessage(@PathVariable String chatId,
                              @ModelAttribute(name = "message") Message message,
                              Model model){
        Chat chat = chatService.findChatById(Long.parseLong(chatId));
        message.setSender((AuthUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        if(Objects.equals(chat.getUsers().get(0).getId(), message.getSender().getId())){
            message.setReceiver(chat.getUsers().get(1));
        }
        else{
            message.setReceiver(chat.getUsers().get(0));
        }
        message.setSendingTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        message.setForwarded(false);
        message.setChat(chat);
        messageService.sendMessage(message);
        return String.format("redirect:/chat/%s", chatId);
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:each="message : ${chat.messageList}">
        <p th:text="${message.sender.username}"></p>
        <p th:text="${message.sendingTime}"></p>
        <p th:text="${message.text}"></p>
    </div>
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/chat/{chatId}/send(chatId=${chat.id})}" id="message">
        <label for="messageText"> Enter your message
        </label>
        <textarea id="messageText" name="text">
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look at websockets